# Collecting and comparing ruby hashes inside array

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby Array that has multiple hashes inside it. Looks as follows:

```
arr_hsh = [
      {
        'name': 'Outdoor',
        'game_code': 'C5',
        'score': '61.68',
      },
      {
        'name': 'Indoor',
        'game_code': 'C6',
        'score': '37.54',
      }
]
```

I want to return **game_code** and **score** pair with the highest score value.

How can I achieve this without doing multiple iterations.

If I do

```
arr_hsh.collect {|p| "#{p[:game_code]}: #{p[:score]}"}
```

Its just returning this

```
["C5: 61.68", "C6: 37.54"]
```

but I want `[C5 => 61.68]`

How can I get this?

Comment: Is `[C5 => 61.68]` supposed to be an array of hashes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) method in this way and [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-then) (or [Object#yield_self](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-yield_self) for older versions of Ruby):

```
arr_hsh.max_by { |h| h['score'] }.then { |res| { res[:game_code] => res[:score] } }
#=> {"C5"=>"61.68"}
```

The first part is working this way:

```
arr_hsh.max_by { |h| h['score'] }
#=> {:name=>"Outdoor", :game_code=>"C5", :score=>"61.68"}
```

The second part takes this output and builds the final Hash, if this is the object you want or whathever.

Consider to convert the score to float, currently is a string.

Comment: `arr_hsh.max_by { |h| h[:score] }.values_at(:game_code,:score).to_h` for even older versions. And `Hash[*arr_hsh.max_by { |h| h[:score] }.values_at(:game_code,:score)]` all the way back to 1.8.7. Also `score` is not a string in the proposed `Hash` prior to 2.2 the `Hash` would actually just be a syntax error and afterwards those strings would be treated as `Symbol`s

Comment: If `37.54` were changed to `9.54` you get the same result, which would be correct, yet `'61.68' > '9.54' #=> false`. Please explain. Good reminder about `then`.